# Can Wordpress used as a CMS?

Tags: cms

I saw many people use WordPress as a CMS, is that common? but the problem I noticed is that the download in such sites is slow, is WordPress slow?

Comment: http://www.downwithdesign.com/web-design/content-management-systems-comparison/  Voting to close as "primarily opinion based"

Comment: Your questions fall downs to the definitions of "CMS" and "slow", which are wildly different, depending on whom you ask. I concur this is completely matter of opinion in the form you asked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress IS a CMS. It hasn't been just a blogging platform for a long time.

And no, it's not slow if you don't make it slow. WP out of the box is really fast, but people slow it down with poorly-written plugins and themes.

You can do whatever you want with Wordpress, as it has hooks for basically everything. And you can find a lot of information in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/). There are also tons of tutorials online.

Comment: So why Plugins slow it down? and if I want to write my own Plugin what language do I need to learn?

Comment: @sali you need to learn php and WordPress itself to write plugins for WordpPress, i am assuming that you know HTML, CSS .etc